# Can the moon turn red even without an eclipse?

Tags: the-moon

My friend posted a picture of the moon as if there was an eclipse because it was so red but there wasn't a scheduled eclipse at the time (it was last night, from the Philippines).

I'm a little concerned because how else is that possible? It was in Manila so I guess there was a lot of smoke in the air but I don't know if that's the reason behind the moon's redness.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pollution from (for example) wildfires can cause the moon to appear red. It is normally not noticed unless the moon is low in the sky.

Earthsky magazine is reporting that [red sunsets and red moons are being reported across the USA.](http://earthsky.org/earth/red-moon-sun-wildfire-smoke-images-aug-sept-2017) caused by wildfires. Even when the moon is quite high in the sky. I believe that fires from logging in the jungles of Borneo and the Philippines can have the same effect.

This has also been answered on https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12223/why-were-both-the-sun-and-the-moon-red-today

Comment: I might add that near-horizon moon looks more orange to me :-), and that one should be very cautious about trusting the color balance of your average digital camera when shooting in dark or near-dark conditions.